# Python Filling NxN with a lookup table

Tags: python, lookup

I am trying iterate through NxN matrix to fill using a lookup table. I am used to VBA doing two for loop but are not entirely sure how to get started on Python. Below is an example of what I am trying to do. Thanks in advance

Template (to be filled):

| -------- | -------------- | John | Anne | Ryan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class A | Maths |  |  |  |
| Class B | Maths |  |  |  |
| Class C | Science |  |  |  |
| Class D | Science |  |  |  |
| Class E | English |  |  |  |
| Class F | English |  |  |  |

Above template is to be filled using a vlookup table (or another way in Python)ץ

Vlookup table:

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| John, Maths | X |
| John, Science | Y |
| Johh, English | XX |
| Anne, Maths | MM |
| Anne, Science | X |
| Anne, English | YY |
| Ryan, Maths | M |
| Ryan, Science | XX |
| Ryan, English | YYAX |

The desired output should be:

| -------- | -------------- | John | Anne | Ryan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class A | Maths | X | MM | M |
| Class B | Maths | X | MM | M |
| Class C | Science | Y | X | XX |
| Class D | Science | Y | X | XX |
| Class E | English | XX | YY | YYAX |
| Class F | English | XX | YY | YYAX |

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: In what form are those tables available? Is this an excel file? Is it a dataframe? A .csv? Please clarify and provide a [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the Vlookup and Template table are in "dataframe" format (python) named "Vlookup_df" and "Template_df" respectively. The implementation is:

```
import pandas as pd
for i in range(Vlookup_df.shape[0]):
   str_arr = Vlookup_df["Name"][i].split(",")
   name = str_arr[0]
   subject =  str_arr[1]
   data = Vlookup_df["Number"][i]
   Template_df[name][subject ] = data
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have issue running the last 2 lines with below error "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame". I tried to ignore this warning but the DF just returns blank.